# Elasticsearch - EXISTS syntax + Filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query for a date range where a particular field exists.  This seems like it would be easy but I am sensing that the keyword "exists" has changed per the documentation. I am on 5.4. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-exists-filter.html

I use @timestamp for dates and the field "error_data" is in the mapping and only appears if an error condition is found.

Here is my query....

```
GET /filebeat-2017.07.25/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : {
            "range" : {
                "@timestamp" : {
                    "gte" : "now-5m",
                    "lte" : "now-1m"
                }
            }
          },
          "exists": {
          "field": "error_data"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

but it says that "[bool] query does not support [exists]" whereas the following does not work either but gets an parsing error message of "[exists] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]" on line 6 column 9.  Thanks for your help.

```
GET /filebeat-2017.07.25/_search
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "error_data"
        }, 
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : {
            "range" : {
                "@timestamp" : {
                    "gte" : "now-5m",
                    "lte" : "now-1m"
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Try like this:

```
GET /filebeat-2017.07.25/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : [
            {
              "range" : {
                "@timestamp" : {
                    "gte" : "now-5m",
                    "lte" : "now-1m"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "error_data"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. the `bool/filter` clause must be an array if you have several clauses to put in it:

Comment: Thank you.  When I do that though I get this error  {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] query does not support [exists]",
        "line": 12,
        "col": 21
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[bool] query does not support [exists]",
    "line": 12,
    "col": 21
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: I don't think you're really using the query from my answer.

Comment: You are correct.....it worked well.  Copy/Paste is better than splicing in by hand.  Very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: @Val - Would you be willing to lend a helping hand please on this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340002/querying-elasticsearch-address-based-index   -- It would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.